# Java object: value for comparison in if statement, operator overloading

Tags: java, object, return

Is it possible to define the value used for if statement comparison for custom objects?

I have:

public class element implements Comparable {

```
public int value;
public int[] sequence;
public int length;

public element(){}   

public element(int val){
    this.value = val;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return
}
```

}

I would like to use and if statement as follows:

> if (element1 > element2) ..

Instead of a traditional:

> if (element1.value > element2.value) ..

I have been unable to acomplish this with comparators, toString() etc

Comment: What are `element1` and `element2`? If they are objects of type `element` then you can do `element1.compareTo(element2)` if you implement `compareTo()` correctly.

Comment: You should try to be more specific. Your requirement isn't clear.

Comment: No operator overloading in java. `<`, `>` can only be used for numbers (byte, short, char, int, long, float, double).

Comment: Operator overloading is not supported in java. You can call element1.compareTo(element2) for comparison and make sure that compareTo returns -1,0 and 1 as required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use object references with the `>` operator, per [JLS 15.20.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1); Java does not support operator overloading.  But you are on the right track with using a `Comparator`.

```
if (comparator.compare(element1, element2) > 0)  // if (element1 > element2)
```

It is also possible if your class is `Comparable<Element>`, i.e. comparable to other elements.

```
if (element1.compareTo(element2) > 0)  // if (element1 > element2)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible in Java. From the [JLS §15.20.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1):

> **The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator
>   must be a type that is convertible ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to a primitive numeric
>   type, or a compile-time error occurs.**

This would be possible in a language like Python, in which almost all operators can be overloaded to work with non-standard classes.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support this. you may use something like follows instead:

```
if (element1.compareTo(element2) > 0) {

}
```

and in your compareTo method, do like this:

```
public int compareTo(YourClassObject o) {
    return (this.value - YourClassObject.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java does not provide support for operator overloading, comparing the two objects using a method which performs the required comparision is the best option available.

```
WrapperClass.compare(object1, object2) > 0 for object1.value > object2.value
WrapperClass.compare(object1, object2) < 0 for object1.value < object2.value
WrapperClass.compare(object1, object2) = 0 for object1.value == object2.value
```

String is one of the class which provides operator overloading like with the concatenation operator.

```
String str1 = "This ";
String str2 = "is a string";
str1 + str2 equals "This is a string"
```